# Combine Facebook login and permission request into one

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

I am trying to create a dialog that asks users to login with Facebook. In reality I don’t care much for the login per se: all I really want is permission to post photos on behalf of the user; nothing else. Below is my Dialog in its entirety. Will someone please correct the code for me? Right now its crashing with some NPE within the Facebook library. I compare my code with the sample HelloFacebookSampleActivity. I can see that the two are obviously different. But I can’t seem to fix mine correctly. Again, I am hoping to at once ask the user to Login and get the permission as opposed to doing it in two steps.

```
public class FacebookOptInFragment extends DialogFragment {
    private final String TAG = FacebookOptInFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private LoginButton loginButton;
    private GraphUser user;
    private static final String PERMISSION = "publish_actions";

    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if ((exception instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException || exception instanceof FacebookAuthorizationException)) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(FacebookOptInFragment.this.getActivity())
                .setTitle("Cancel")
                .setMessage("Permission not granted")
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", null)
                .show();
        }
        updateUI();
    }

    private void updateUI() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
            //user has agreed to post photos… so make a note of that
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.facebook_optin, container);
        loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setUserInfoChangedCallback(new LoginButton.UserInfoChangedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {
                FacebookOptInFragment.this.user = user;
                updateUI();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

}
```

The error

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)


 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.containsKey(ConcurrentHashMap.java:911)
    at com.facebook.internal.Utility.queryAppSettings(Utility.java:664)
    at com.facebook.widget.LoginButton$1.doInBackground(LoginButton.java:678)
    at com.facebook.widget.LoginButton$1.doInBackground(LoginButton.java:1)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    ... 4 more
```

---

---

---

Looking at the HelloFacebookSampleActivity, I see that the Login process is separate from the permission request process. Is there a way to combine the two? That is, when I ask a user to Login with Facebook, I “automatically” get the permissions I need. What I mean specifically is that I don’t want two different windows at two different times. This is important for my case because all I really want is the permission to share photos for the user; the login itself is irrelevant. So how might I combine the two?

The sample codes from HelloFacebookSampleActivity mentioned are

For Login

```
loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setUserInfoChangedCallback(new LoginButton.UserInfoChangedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {
                HelloFacebookSampleActivity.this.user = user;
                updateUI();
                // It's possible that we were waiting for this.user to be populated in order to post a
                // status update.
                handlePendingAction();
            }
        });
```

For permission request

```
session.requestNewPublishPermissions(new  Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSION));
```

Will someone please show a complete code snippet showing how to ask for permission while login in. I am very new to this so filling in the blanks is difficult, so a complete snippet would be helpful, which is why I submit my entire class for editing.

Answer (score 0):

publish_actions is considered a "publish" permission, and normally needs to be a separate request than other "read" permissions (e.g. email, likes, etc). If the only permission you want is publish_actions, then you can try something like:

```
loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
loginButton.setPublishPermissions('publish_actions');
...
```

The NPE you're getting is likely because you didn't put the app ID in your AndroidManifest.xml (see the [getting started guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started)) rather than the permissions.

Comment: I have app id in manifest as `<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>` and I have the string in the xml resource. So why would it not see the app id?

Comment: Which version of the SDK are you using? I'm assuming that your app crashes before it switches over to the FB app for login? Also, does the HelloFacebook sample work for you?